# AWS SQS DLQ messages become not visible without consumer/trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

In the architecture I'm working on I have a simple SQS queue with a DLQ.

I have noticed a specific behaviour that doesn't make sense in my mind on the **DLQ**: even if my DLQ has **NO lambda trigger** it looks like the messages can become **not visible** sometimes like the queue is trying to process them anyway.

Is it the expected behaviour?

There is anything else (in addition to a lambda trigger) that can make a message not visible in the queue?

[image]

[image]

In my simple tests, I have just sent a message on the main queue (where there's a lambda attached), in a way that was failing enough times to be moved in the DLQ. From the screenshot above in monitoring, you can see how when the DLQ was holding at some point one message only this started to become not visible 2 times for no apparent reason.

Comment: have you checked the retention period? the message is deleted after that

Comment: retention period is set as default (4 days)

Comment: Hi Massimo, sorry I got it wrong. I thought the message had been deleted after some time, but it is just not visible for a few minutes. I'm thinking about the delivery delay config, it makes the message invisible for some time but it's just a guess. By the way, would you mind posting the print of the configuration from that queue? Would be helpful.

Comment: @JuanFontes updated my original post with more info

Comment: Were you by any chance polling the queue - either with a script or via the console? That would produce this behaviour.